# Trying to build an image classifier using keras

Tags: pandas, keras

I am trying to build an image classifier with keras and the size of my dataset requires me to use the ImageDataGenerator class along with its flow_from_dataframe method. This is the code I am using.

```
training = pd.read_csv("dataset/train/training.csv")

training = (training[(training["view_type"].isin(["view_4","view_5"]))])

training = (training[["id", "class"]]).reset_index(drop = True)

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. /255)

training.head()


id  class
0   image_view4_0.jpg   lace_up
1   image_view4_1.jpg   lace_up
2   image_view4_2.jpg   zipper
3   image_view4_3.jpg   lace_up
4   image_view4_4.jpg   hook&look

train_generaor = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = training, 
                              directory = "dataset/train/images/", 
                                             xcol = "id", 
                                             ycol = "class", 
                                             has_ext = True, 
                                             class_mode = "categorical", 
                                             target_size = (224, 224))
```

However, when I run the train generator in colab, I get the following error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2524             try:
-> 2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'filename'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-e1787553cadc> in <module>()
      7                                              target_size = (224, 224),
      8                                              color_mode  = "rgb",
----> 9                                              validate_filenames = True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py in flow_from_dataframe(self, dataframe, directory, x_col, y_col, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, interpolation, drop_duplicates, **kwargs)
    664             subset=subset,
    665             interpolation=interpolation,
--> 666             drop_duplicates=drop_duplicates
    667         )
    668 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py in __init__(self, dataframe, directory, image_data_generator, x_col, y_col, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, interpolation, dtype, drop_duplicates)
    118         self.dtype = dtype
    119         # check that inputs match the required class_mode
--> 120         self._check_params(df, x_col, y_col, classes)
    121         if drop_duplicates:
    122             df.drop_duplicates(x_col, inplace=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py in _check_params(self, df, x_col, y_col, classes)
    162                              .format(self.class_mode, self.allowed_class_modes))
    163         # check that filenames/filepaths column values are all strings
--> 164         if not all(df[x_col].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))):
    165             raise ValueError('All values in column x_col={} must be strings.'
    166                              .format(x_col))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2137             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
   2138         else:
-> 2139             return self._getitem_column(key)
   2140 
   2141     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
   2144         # get column
   2145         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 2146             return self._get_item_cache(key)
   2147 
   2148         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
   1840         res = cache.get(item)
   1841         if res is None:
-> 1842             values = self._data.get(item)
   1843             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
   1844             cache[item] = res

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
   3841 
   3842             if not isna(item):
-> 3843                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
   3844             else:
   3845                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2525                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2526             except KeyError:
-> 2527                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2528 
   2529         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'filename'
```

What is going wrong? I have tried multiple things to fix this but cannot figure out why this is happening

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the filename you are using is incorrect. If your data is in the same directory as working directory, use `'./dataset/train/images/'`

Comment: I have used `./dataset/train/images/` and yes my data is in the working directory but still i get the same error. However my images folder contain images which are not in the "id" column of my dataframe, it should not cause the problem but i am a newbie, so just making a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the keras documentation, 'filename' is what it expects in the argument `xcol`. `xcol` refers to a column in dataframe supposed to contain the image path relative to what you provided in the argument `directory`.

So you are just providing the wrong columns as arguments. Change the column names of your 2-column dataframe:

```
training.columns = ['path', 'class']
```

Then change your arguments to what is required:

```
train_generaor = datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = training, 
                                             directory = "dataset/train/images/", 
                                             xcol = "path", 
                                             ycol = "class", 
                                             has_ext = True, 
                                             class_mode = "categorical", 
                                             target_size = (224, 224))
```

Comment: This should solve your 'filename' error, but you will also need to one-hot encode your categorical labels in the 'class' column. Try this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html

Comment: Okay i figured it out, it was a silly mistake, it should be x_col not xcol. Thanks for your help and the quick response